# Django: Queryset not saving changes to value?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Here, `result` is a Queryset. I am going through it and updating the value for it's `price` attribute to match what I get from the `price_map.price` value in my second query to `Product.objects`.

This works and updates the prices accordingly. Until it goes into the `.order_by` method. Then, all of the values of `price` return to what they originally were.

```
if sort_by in valid_sorts:
            for item in result:
                retrieved_item = Product.objects.get(name=item.name).get_pricing_info(self.request.session.get('visitors_country'))
                if retrieved_item['price_map'] is None:
                    print 'we got a none here! ', item.name
                else:
                    item.price = retrieved_item['price_map'].price

            if sort_by == 'highlow':
                result = result.order_by('-price')
            elif sort_by == 'lowhigh':
                result = result.order_by('price')
            elif sort_by == 'newest':
                result = result.order_by('-date','-price')
            elif sort_by == 'relevancy':
                pass
```

If I add in some print statements for just before and just after the `.order_by` call, here is the output I get:

```
Just before the order!
79.99
119.99
99.99
69.99
119.99
89.99
69.99
69.99
99.99
44.99
599.99
599.99
69.99
69.99
69.99
69.99
249.99
799.99
119.99
139.99
199.99
249.99
139.99
149.99
139.99
69.99
139.99
199.99
69.99
29.99
0.0
139.99
34.99
54.99
119.99
149.99
69.99
69.99
89.99
119.99
119.99
149.99
149.99
1699.99
69.99
249.99
39.99
39.99
39.99
599.99
999.99
199.99
49.99
119.99
119.99
249.99
99.99
99.99
199.99
69.99
99.99
39.99
169.99
this is the high low sort!
1499.99
599.99
599.99
399.99
349.99
299.99
249.99
209.99
199.99
199.99
179.99
159.99
159.99
129.99
129.99
119.99
119.99
119.99
119.99
119.99
99.99
99.99
89.99
89.99
89.99
69.99
69.99
69.99
69.99
59.99
59.99
49.99
49.99
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

Stack trace for the issue when I try to save the item after changing the price value in the for loop:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/generic_views.py", line 120, in get
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 45, in get_form
    return form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/generic_views.py", line 94, in get_form_kwargs
    kwargs = super(FacetedSearchMixin, self).get_form_kwargs()
  File "/home/user/.virtualenvs/rf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/generic_views.py", line 65, in get_form_kwargs
    kwargs.update({'searchqueryset': self.get_queryset()})
  File "/home/user/Documents/sandbox/opt/rock/ro/rf/products/views.py", line 344, in get_queryset
    item.save()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: are you saving the item instance after updating price ? `item.save()` ?

Comment: I tried adding in `item.save` but I am getting an error `NoneType object is not callable.`

Answer (score 2):

`order_by` function returns a new queryset instance. Because of the lazy nature of queryset, the new `result` queryset (with `order_by`) will execute another query to fetch data from the database.

Since you are not saving the updated item, the value is just updated at the python object level and not saved in the database. So when you are accessing the `price` with the new `result` queryset, it shows the result fetched from the database which is still the older one.

So to solve the issue, either sort the objects at python level or save the items before calling the `order_by` function.

Comment: I see I see. Thank you for the information on how that works. Is there a good way to sort a Searchqueryset object without it turning into a list? The rest of the code depends on this being a SQS object.

Comment: You can do sorting on any queryset using `order_by` method. It will sort the data at database level  (before caching the results in `_result_cache` list). But in your case, you are changing the value of the individual objects after fetching the results. So if you are not saving the results again, you have to do it at python level.

Comment: I see. So would you have any idea why `item.save()` is giving me an error? It's saying `NoneType object is not callable`...but, as far as I know, no objects that I am calling `.save()` on are NoneType (else they would have been caught in my `if:` statement...and when I print out the types of each item, none are `NoneType`).

Comment: Add stack trace of the error in the question. I think the `item` object is not `None`, because in that case the error would be `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'` . So maybe somewhere in save method, it is trying to call a `NoneType` object. You can use python debugger `pdb` or `ipdb` to get details of execution at every step.

Comment: Added the stack trace into the question. I really appreciate you coming back to this question and helping me figure out what's going on with this. I'll try checking out those Python debuggers too.

Comment: Not able to conclude much from the stack trace. Try using `ipdb`. It will provide you good details. On a bit different note, do you even want to save the `item` object because it looks like you are doing query for each user request based on its country. So if you are saving, `item` price will keep on changing in the database using current user's country.

Comment: I would definitely prefer not to save and instead just sort the results of the query on the Python level. However, I haven't been able to find a good way to do this since the rest of the code is expecting to be fed a SearchQuerySet. At this point, I almost feel like I just need to do a big re-write of this whole component.